# Unreachable spring-beans.dtd

Tags: spring, uima

We are using Apache UIMA-AS 2.6 which at runtime generates a Spring context file starting with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans   PUBLIC "-//Spring//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/spring-beans.dtd">
```

On 2016-05-14 23:45 UTC, the DTD wasn't online anymore:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 522 for URL: http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd
```

This error persisted for a while (at least until 2016-05-15 15:00 UTC, maybe later) and all our online services were down!...

We have then downloaded the DTD from Spring Reference http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/springbeansdtd.html (version 1.2.x...), and saved it on our website. Then we have changed the XSL distributed by UIMA-AS ($UIMA_HOME/bin/dd2spring.xsl) in order to change the DTD URL.

Where can we find any information on healthy spring DTD repository? 
Anyone has a better way to avoid this kind of runtime error?

Comment: Please consider opening an issue for this on the UIMA issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UIMA - there should be a way for AS to ship this file and to resolve the URL to the shipped one instead of trying a remote request.

Answer (score 0):

I just pointed my browser to http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd and it does not generate an error.

The actual spring-beans.dtd is packaged in spring-beans-.jar in org\springframework\beans\factory\xml\ folder.

Answer (score 0):

The uima-as code generates xml files that include the dtd reference:

http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd

The code snip above says the dtd ref was:

http://www.springframework.org/spring-beans.dtd

This form is incorrect (it's missing the "/dtd/" in the middle), and not generated by uima-as - perhaps it was a manual cut/paste error?  The other form appears to work.